# How many applications can be connected to one MongoDB atlas cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

Sorry if this question is stupid but I can't seem to find a straight answer to it anywhere.

Also, if it is one application or more that one application, why?

Comment: There is no limit on # of connected applications.

Comment: Each Atlas tier has a limit on the number of inbound TCP connections, it doesn't matter how many applications are on the other end.